# RangeQuery for Searching Date Type in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i made a query with elasticsearch client in java , and when i try to searching a date they give me this erros

> Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[-AAmwvoOSUmuCZKhW-SZug][car][0]: RemoteTransportException[[-AAmwvo][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[failed to parse date field [Wed Dec 04 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019]

my query code is like :

```
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String sourceDate = "2019-12-04T00:00:00.000Z";


        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(sourceDate);

 if (query == null) {

                        query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("Date Field")

                                .from(myDate)

                                .to(myDate)

                                .includeLower(true)

                                .includeUpper(false));

                    } else {

                        query = query.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("Date Field")

                                .from(myDate)

                                .to(myDate)
                                .includeLower(true)

                                .includeUpper(false));

            }
```

any idea about this problem? Thank you

Comment: The date format doesn't match the value in your `sourceDate` field.

Comment: i already try this but i got the same errors : SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'");

Comment: Can you try passing 2 different dates in `to()` and `from()` methods

Comment: i got the same errors :/